# Horizontal scroll bar - WP Thesis - WHY?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

My site shows a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom -- it's like I have a lot of extra space to the right of my theme -- but there's really nothing there.

Can someone tell me how I can correct this?

I am using Wordpress 3.0, Thesis theme with the full-width framework.

Thanks!!!

Comment: in what browser you get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have this element :

```
<button value="" name="sa" type="submit" class="googlesearch-btn"></button>
```

with this css asigned to it:

```
.googlesearch-btn {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 37px;
    left: 267px;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    width: 35px;
}
```

You should try to make it : display:none;

Comment: diangelo, unfortunately that doesn't remove the hz scroll bar -- and it makes the search button go dead --

Comment: @mptorr - It's part of the underlying problem though. Reposition  .googlesearch-btn, and also give .social-block a width of 130px and your horizontal scroll bar will disappear. This is better than using overflow:hidden or overflow-x:hidden because they will simply horizontally truncate your real content when it is wider then the browser window.

Comment: Alohci -- that's pretty awesome -- I forgot to establish the width for .social-block. I've done as you suggested - thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know in what browser you  get this behavior but in css you can use `overflow-x:hidden` to hide the horizontal scrollbar

```
html, body {overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Comment: I see it with Firefox 3.6 on a Mac

Comment: It happens in IE, FF, Safari, Chrome.

Comment: Awesome! This solved my overflow problem that was hosing up the display on the ipad

Answer (score 0):

If you can add extra CSS styles to the theme simply using wordpress, add in the following style:

```
.full_width {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

If you can't do that, but can edit the original stylesheets provided with the theme, edit the "layout.css" file (from url http://www.thedailytail.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/layout.css?120410-40254 when I visited), somewhere around line 21 find the style for .full_width and add in the line

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks a lot guys, overflow:hidden did the trick. Cheers!